# Android Debug tool - Tracer for OpenGL ES - Can it be used for a service?

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-service, android-debug

I have a service which creates a dialog window, for the UI part. Basically, it has no main launcher activity.
Now, I want to debug overdraw issues in my service using tracer tool as explained here - http://developer.android.com/tools/help/gltracer.html & http://www.curious-creature.org/docs/android-performance-case-study-1.html.

Now, tracer asks for a main launcher activity on start. But my service has none. So, when i start tracing, it gives me an error that intent for main launcher activity was not resolved.

The error I get is : "activity not started. unable to resolve intent {act = android.intent.action.MAIN cat = [android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] pck = com.sec.android.inputmethod}"

It seems this tool will work only when an app has a main launcher activity.
But I need to use it for a service. Does anybody know of a work-around ?

If anybody has worked in this area, help !